# R: calculate row difference by category in R

Tags: r

I want to calculate the difference between two days by month, for instance:

```
attach(airquality)
head(airquality)

  Ozone Solar.R Wind Temp Month Day
1    41     190  7.4   67     5   1
2    36     118  8.0   72     5   2
3    12     149 12.6   74     5   3
4    18     313 11.5   62     5   4
5    NA      NA 14.3   56     5   5
6    28      NA 14.9   66     5   6
```

My output is like:

```
Month Day  temp_diff
5     1      5
5     2      2
5     3      -12
```

The calculation will stop at the last day for each month, e.g. for May31, it won't calculate the temp_diff by substracting temp of June 1 and temp of May 31.

Before calculating I need to order the data by month and day so they can be calculated correctly.

I was thinking to use: `by(airquality[,1:4],Month,function)` but cannot figure out how to write this function, help?

Comment: `cbind(airquality[-nrow(airquality),c("Month","Day")],temp_diff=diff(airquality$Temp))`

Comment: @ToToRo It is a bit unclear from the description what your expected result would be.  Do you want difference of temp for each Month or for the whole dataset?

Comment: @akrun Difference of temp for each Month

Comment: @ToToRO Isnt that what I showed in the solution?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the dataset is ordered by `Month` and `day`

Using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

 airquality %>%
 group_by(Month) %>% 
 arrange(Month, Day) %>% #if not ordered
 mutate(temp_diff=c(diff(Temp),NA)) %>%
 select(Month, Day, temp_diff)%>%
 head()

 #      Month Day temp_diff
 #1     5   1         5
 #2     5   2         2
 #3     5   3       -12
 #4     5   4        -6
 #5     5   5        10
 #6     5   6        -1
```

Or using `base R`

```
airquality$temp_diff <- with(airquality, ave(Temp, Month,
                          FUN=function(x) c(diff(x), NA)))
```

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
 DT <- setDT(airquality)[, temp_diff:=c(diff(Temp),NA), by=Month]
```